# pass function to function with different number of variables

Tags: python, function

Suppose I have a function `def foo(A, B)`.

Now I have another function `bar(func)`, where `func` is a function that takes only one variable. I want to pass in `foo` as `func`, but with the second variable `B` always fixed to 300. How can I do that?

Comment: Search for "partial application".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `lambda`:

```
bar(lambda x: foo(x,300))
```

basically,

```
func = lambda x: x*x
```

is more or less equivalent to:

```
def func(x):
   return x*x
```

So in this case, we use something that's more or less equivalent to:

```
def new_func(x):
    return foo(x,300)
```

and then we pass the equivalent of `new_func` to `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda is easiest, but you could also use functools.partial for more complex cases:

```
import functools

bar(functools.partial(foo, B=300))
```